# Issue while using the temp table in the SP with SSIS 2014

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2014, sql-server-data-tools, sql-server-2012-datatools

I have a SSIS 2014 package where I am using a SP. That SP is creating the temp table and inserting data into that temp table and returning the result set. When I use the package with SQL SERVER 2005 then it is working fine but when I use the SQL SERVER 2014 database then it is returning the below error:

> SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
>   An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "The metadata could not be determined because statement 'INSERT INTO #tblTemp
>       (
>           id
>          ,username
>          ,indicator' in procedure 'p_GetFullData' uses a temp table.".

I have also SET FMTONLY OFF but it is also not working.

Answer (score 1):

Set FMT Only Off no longer works! I was surprised too.

Instead you can trick SSIS by running a Select where 1=0 as the first Select in the stored procedure. Then carry on as normal in your stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following:

1. Enable delay validation
2. Use Table variable instead of Temp table